# Wireless, powerline or ethernet right next to electric cable

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11

I need a new point of access to our existing network. We have power sockets but no Ethernet cable on the spot. I see three possible solutions to achieve this:

1. Add a new WiFi6 router and connect it to our main WiFi6 router.
2. Use two powerline adapters.
3. Install a Cat6 cable in the same cable pipe in which the electric cable runs. (they would be really close, practically right beside each other for ~9 meters).

What do you think which option would be the best (throughput, reliability, etc...)?

Comment: Likely the best option is fiber.

Comment: Your first two options are off-topic consumer-grade devices, and the third option is probably illegal (check with your building inspector, fire marshal, etc.).

Comment: Wireless bridges are not exclusively a "home network" thing. I've set up several to link neighboring buildings where burying cable was not an option. (they don't want to wreck their new parking lot, don't own the connecting properties, etc.)

Comment: @RickyBeam Wireless bridges are not necessarily consumer grade, but *WiFi6 routers* are.

Comment: There are several enterprise 802.11ax ("wifi6") systems on the market today. And that number is growing. Yes, it's far more common in "home networking" devices, but not exclusively.

Comment: Thank you, the answer of @Ricky helped a lot. I did not chased the wall again but tried a WiFi6 bridge and it can transfer the ~350 Mbps my service provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option one is a "wireless bridge". Certainly common enough, but wifi is often too slow and unstable. Option two is similar to #1. (slow, and surprisingly easy to break.)

Option three is *code violation.* You **cannot** put low voltage cabling in the same conduit as high voltage cabling. This is for safety reasons; there's very little concern of powerline noise (50/60Hz) coupling to ethernet (MHz), but *a lot* of concern if power (120-250v) ever touches a data wire.

To answer the question... you're best option is to hire a competent, professional communications electrician to install the necessary ethernet cable(s). In my experience, for a few drops, it's far cheaper than buying gear to do #1 or #2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was almost sure #3 is not a real option. I do not want to chase the wall (again :) ) if it is not absolutely necessary, my wife would kill me :) Do you think a modern WiFi6 wireless bridge would be insufficient? What throughput do you expect on ~7 meters (and one firewall between the routers).

Comment: Also, cutting a hole through a wall is not that difficult. (a "pass-thru" box.) As long as it's not a fire rated wall -- physically easy, sure, but the hole has to be sealed.

Comment: Unfortunately a hole (or two) is not enough, I must chase the wall on ~2 meters to be able to lead the cable above the ceiling properly, above the ceiling the next 7 meter is already prepared. I could drill a hole but in this case the cable would run in the next room :) A surface conduit would be ugly so the only option is chasing the wall if I need a properly installed a data wire. This is why I would like to find an alternative. If you say a wireless bridge would be insufficient and the powerline solutions are unreliable the chasing seems to remain the only solution.