# How do i prevent dataloss, when installing an ethernet cable fairly close to an electric cable?

Tags: ethernet, cable, data, power

I want to install an ethernet cable and an electric cable (230V) right next to each other (same cable tube, currently 20mm in diameter, length up to 100m (i think its under 75m but i didn't measure yet)).

Here are my worries:

Even so the ethernet cable is fairly well shielded (currently CAT. 7 S/FTP, AWG 23), i'm worried that we will encounter noticeable dataloss, when using this construction at full power.

While the ethernet cable will be the only source of internet for up to 30 pc's, the electric cable has to power a majority of those (there are other electric cable already installed but not enough to power all pc's (different tubes)).

I could test it with way lower workload. I'm not sure how significant a test with 2 laptops could be.

The real test is an old-school "LAN" party, but as you might have guessed, at that time it's too late to change the installation.

Im up for suggestions (do i need further shielding, do i need another cable tube for the electric cable and if yes, how much is the minimum distance for parallel installation or will it be fine?)

Comment: Installing low- and high voltage cabling right next to each other is illegal in most jurisdictions, and it can get your building shut down. See the above linked question, [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/70752/8499), and [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/28704/8499).

Comment: You can't run high voltage (power) and low voltage (data) in the same conduit. That's not allowed *anywhere*. As for noise, power is 50/60hz, ethernet is in the megahz... they will not interfere with each other. (two parallel wires don't induce much current)

Comment: @Ricky I wouldn't take *they will not interfere with each other* for granted - given the number of switching PSUs (and possibly bad/missing PFC), the amount of transients could be quite large.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks alot. i didnt find the second question. It didnt show up. I won't use the same cable tube for both cables.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you *don't* install (copper) data and power cables like that. Power and data should be at least 5 cm apart for longer runs (do check local regulations for legal restrictions).

You should consider fiber which is practically immune to EMI. If cost is an issue check out preterminated fiber with a keystone panel.

Comment: Well, thank you for clarifying. I won't use the same cable tube. The only question remaining is how far they need to be apart. The cable tubes will be mostly underground (earth/stones). Do you know/think that 10cm apart will do? Is there a norm or something?